# string.IndexOf performance

Tags: c#, .net, performance

This simple piece of c# code that is meant to find script blocks in HTML takes 0.5 seconds to run on a 74K char string with only 9 script blocks in it. This is undebuged release binary on 2.8Ghz i7 CPU. I made several runs though this code to make sure that performance is not impeded by JIT. It is not.

This is VS2010 .NET 4.0 Client Profile. x64

Why is this so slow?

```
                int[] _exclStart = new int[100];
                int[] _exclStop = new int[100];
                int _excl = 0;
                for (int f = input.IndexOf("<script", 0); f != -1; )
                {
                    _exclStart[_excl] = f;
                    f = input.IndexOf("</script", f + 8);
                    if (f == -1)
                    {
                        _exclStop[_excl] = input.Length;
                        break;
                    }
                    _exclStop[_excl] = f;
                    f = input.IndexOf("<script", f + 8);
                    ++_excl;
                }
```

Comment: try using regular expression that is compiled

Comment: I have to guess that *input* is actually a property that's very expensive to retrieve.  Make a copy.

Comment: input is a string that is already there. It is 74,000+ characters long. There is no perf penalty for retirieving it.

Comment: @Ghostrider did you ever find out what outside of this code was making it so slow?

Comment: string.IndexOf is just plain slow - now much that can be done there. I ended up rewriting the whole app (it was a small one) in C++. Works lightning fast now :)

Comment: @Ghostrider did you not see my post where I highlighted that your problem was something outside this code because your execution times for the exact same code were 50 times slower than my reproduced results  when i used a input string 4.5 times longer?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I used the source on this page as an example, I then duplicated the content 8 times, resulting in a page some 334,312 bytes long. Using StringComparision.Ordinal yields massive performance difference.

```
string newInput = string.Format("{0}{0}{0}{0}{0}{0}{0}{0}", input.Trim().ToLower());
//string newInput = input.Trim().ToLower();

System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
int[] _exclStart = new int[100];
int[] _exclStop = new int[100];
int _excl = 0;
for (int f = newInput.IndexOf("<script", 0, StringComparison.Ordinal); f != -1; )
{
    _exclStart[_excl] = f;
    f = newInput.IndexOf("</script", f + 8, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    if (f == -1)
    {
        _exclStop[_excl] = newInput.Length;
        break;
    }
    _exclStop[_excl] = f;
    f = newInput.IndexOf("<script", f + 8, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    ++_excl;
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
```

running 5 times yields almost the same result for each (the loop timings did not significantly change so for this simple code there is almost no time spent for JIT to compile it)

Output using your original code (in **Milliseconds**):

```
10.2786
11.4671
11.1066
10.6537
10.0723
```

Output using the above code instead (in **Milliseconds**):

```
0.3055
0.2953
0.2972
0.3112
0.3347
```

Notice that my test results are around **0.010 seconds** (original code) and **0.0003 seconds** (for ordinal code). Meaning you have something else wrong other than this code directly.

If as you say, using `StringComparison.Ordinal` does nothing for your performance then that means that either your using incorrect timers to time your performance, or you have a large overhead in reading your `input` value such as reading it from a stream again which you otherwise don't realise.

Tested under Windows 7 x64 running on a 3GHz i5 using .NET 4 Client Profile.

Suggestions:

1. use `StringComparison.Ordinal`
2. Make sure you're using `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` to time performance
3. Declare a local variable for the `input` instead of using values external to the function (eg: `string newInput = input.Trim().ToLower();`)

Again I stress, I am getting **50 times faster** speed for a test data that is apparently over 4 times larger in size using the exact same code that you provide. Meaning my test is running some **200 times faster** than yours which is not something anyone would expect given we're both running same environment and just i5 (me) versus i7 (you).

Comment: The OP said their code runs in 0.5 seconds.  Your timings seem on the same order...

Comment: my returned timings are `TotalMilliseconds` not `TotalSeconds` they're significantly faster. Meaning that the OPs performance problem is not directly in this section of code.

Comment: no problem, I clarified the answer as you made a good point still

Comment: TY for saving my life w/this (even now in 2022). IRONICALLY in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison?view=net-6.0 MS specifically says, "When you call a string comparison method such as String.Compare, String.Equals, or String.IndexOf, you should always call an overload that includes a parameter of type StringComparison so that you can specify the type of comparison that the method performs" ... but they still have the overloads w/o StringComparison and they don't deprecate them! SMH!

Answer (score 5):

The IndexOf overload you're using is culture-sensitive, which will affect performance.  Instead, use:

```
input.IndexOf("<script", 0, StringComparison.Ordinal);
```

Comment: using StringComparison.Ordinal has no measurable effect on performance of this code.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using RegEx for this, it offers significant performance improvement because the expressions are compiled only once. Whereas IndexOf is essentially a loop which runs on per character basis which probably means, you have 3 "loops" within your main for loop, ofcourse, IndexOf won't be as slow as a regular loop, but still when the input size grows the time increases. Regex has inbuilt functions that would return the number and positions of occurrences of each pattern you define.

Edit: this might shed some more light on the performance of IndexOf [IndexOf Perf](http://www.dotnetperls.com/indexof)

Comment: I've tried using compiled RegEx as well - performance is identical. Also tried adding RegexOptions.CultureInvariant to options - zero effect

Answer (score 2):

I just test IndexOf performance with .NET 4.0 on Windows 7

```
public void Test()
{
    var input = "Hello world, I'm ekk. This is test string";

    TestStringIndexOfPerformance(input, StringComparison.CurrentCulture);
    TestStringIndexOfPerformance(input, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
    TestStringIndexOfPerformance(input, StringComparison.Ordinal);

    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void TestStringIndexOfPerformance(string input, StringComparison stringComparison)
{
    var count = 0;
    var startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    TimeSpan result;

    for (var index = 0; index != 1000000; index++)
    {
        count = input.IndexOf("<script", 0, stringComparison);
    }

    result = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(startTime);

    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", stringComparison, count);
    Console.WriteLine("Total time: {0}", result.TotalMilliseconds);
    Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
}
```

**And the result is:**

```
CurrentCulture:
    Total time: 225.4008

InvariantCulture:
    Total time: 187.2003

Ordinal:
    Total time: 124.8003
```

As you can see performance of Ordinal is a little better.

Answer (score 1):

I don't discuss the code here, that probably coul be written with Regex and so on... but in order to me is slow because the **IndexOf()** **inside** the `for` always rescan the string from the beginning ( it always start from index 0 ) try to scan from the last occurrency found instead.